# SQL replacing one value with another

Tags: sql

I have a table known as address_book and I wish to change a value of column "entry_country_id" from 257 to 222. Bear in mind I have other values in this row, but I just want 257 (the value in column entry_country_id) changed to 222.

Comment: when you say _I have other values_, is it in the same column and row. Give us your table structure with sample data to help.

Answer (score 15):

```
UPDATE address_book
SET entry_country_id = 222
WHERE entry_country_id = 257
```

OR

```
UPDATE address_book
SET entry_country_id = '222'
WHERE entry_country_id = '257'
```

if the column contains strings

Answer (score 5):

```
Update address_book
set entry_country_id=222
where entry_country_id=257
```